# Do you have to clear the depth buffer each frame in OpenGL

Tags: depth-map

I am trying to make it so that objects leave trails behind them and if an object is in the back and tries to draw over a previous trail it is transparent because of it.

The problem is whenever I do not GL_CLEAR the depth buffer after each frame the screen goes blank. Is there a way around this in Open GL ES 2.0?

Diagram:
[image]

Comment: Could you post some code and a screen shot of what it looks like, and perhaps an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @user1118321 Good idea. Added!

Comment: Could you expand the explanation of what you intend? Do you want the objects to be opaque in all cases *except* when they are behind a trail? Does this apply only to the trails of other objects, or also to an object's own trails?